# Trouble running Apache arrow java code in windows?

Tags: java, windows, apache-arrow

I am new to Apache Arrow, I was trying to run sample code in Java, and I am using Windows OS for my development.
Below is my code.

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    try(
            BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator();
            ListVector listVector = ListVector.empty("listVector", allocator);
            UnionListWriter listWriter = listVector.getWriter()
        ) {
            int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000 };
            int tmp_index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                listWriter.setPosition(i);
                listWriter.startList();
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    listWriter.writeInt(data[tmp_index]);
                    tmp_index = tmp_index + 1;
                }
                listWriter.setValueCount(3);
                listWriter.endList();
            }
            listVector.setValueCount(4);

            System.out.print(listVector);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.setZero(ArrowBuf.java:1161)
at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.BaseRepeatedValueVector.reallocOffsetBuffer(BaseRepeatedValueVector.java:135)
at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.ListVector.reallocValidityAndOffsetBuffers(ListVector.java:300)
at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.ListVector.startNewValue(ListVector.java:808)
at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.impl.UnionListWriter.startList(UnionListWriter.java:517)
at arrow_pro.check.App.main(App.java:24)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.writer.FieldWriter.close()" because the return value of "org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.impl.PromotableWriter.getWriter()" is null
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.impl.PromotableWriter.close(PromotableWriter.java:396)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.impl.UnionListWriter.close(UnionListWriter.java:121)
    at arrow_pro.check.App.main(App.java:35)
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (16384) Allocator(ROOT) 0/16384/16384/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)

    at org.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator.close(BaseAllocator.java:437)
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.RootAllocator.close(RootAllocator.java:29)
    at arrow_pro.check.App.main(App.java:35)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize MemoryUtil.
at org.apache.arrow.memory.util.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:136)
... 6 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field long java.nio.Buffer.address accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @6895a785
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at org.apache.arrow.memory.util.MemoryUtil.(MemoryUtil.java:84)
... 6 more

I am using these dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
        <artifactId>arrow-vector</artifactId>
        <version>${arrow.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
        <artifactId>arrow-memory-netty</artifactId>
        <version>${arrow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
        <artifactId>arrow-memory-core</artifactId>
        <version>${arrow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: this looks like a module system issue. Can you add what version of Java you are running on and what version of Arrow?

Comment: @L.Blanc I am running on java 8

Comment: I am trying to run on eclipse and created a maven project JRE is 11, but when I am exporting as a jar and trying to execute that jar it's working fine.
I have this version of java in my system.
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-win64) (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you sure you're on Java 8? "does not 'opens ...'" is a Java 9+ exception. See the docs here, it gives the `--add-opens` flag you must pass: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/install.html#installing-from-maven

Comment: li.davidm Thanks, I am using java 8 but, now I am able to run after passing this as VM argument in eclipse 
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem with java 8.

I added **--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED** in VM Arguments in eclipse and it solved my problem.

[image: Please see reference image]